Migrating data into CRM some date values stored with either 4 or 5 hours head
I been migrating data into CRM from SQL server through SSIS(kingswaysoft). Some record's date values stored either 4 or 5 hours ahead .Is it possible to save date as same as source.
how to resolve this issue ? SQL server data's date values in UTC format

In our CRM Destination Component, you could choose the optional setting “Send DateTime values in UTC format” if the datetime values coming in from the Source are in UTC. Please give this a try, and feel free to reach out to our Solutions and Support team if you need further assistance at https://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us

Its working fine now ! Thank you..................
